# SQLPlus script/statement not returning results in Powershell run by Scheduled Task

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, powershell-2.0, windows-server-2008, sqlplus

Purpose - Monitor a specific Queue of data in a Oracle11 SQL server via SQLPlus and Powershell (via Scheduled Task).  Multiple servers are being touched, and the list will be dynamic based on which systems are needing extra attention.

Limitations: I have PS 2.0, Oracle11.2, and SQLPlus 11.2, Windows Server 2k8, Admin Permissions(but can't really install anything like cmdlet's)

Function: I need the PS/SQL script to run in one minute intervals so that we can keep a close eye on the queue.  I currently have a string of bat files accomplishing this, but would really like to make something a bit cleaner and easier to maintain (fewer files to modify, etc).  I have a secondary PS script which just does a Get-Content -wait on the final output file.  This allows myself, and my coworkers (24H staff across two workcenters) to keep a close watch on this.  No, we don't have the most thorough install of everything which would make some of the problems I'm running into easier. :shrug:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass

Set-Location -Path E:\path\path\path\NEW

$filePath1 = "E:\path\path\path\NEW"

$filePath2 = "E:\path\path\path\NEW\Log"

$filePath3 = "E:\path\path\path\NEW\Log\ServerOutput"

$file1 = "E:\path\path\path\NEW\ServerList.txt"

$file2 = "E:\path\path\path\NEW\Log\Queue_Check_$d.log"

$file3 = "E:\path\path\path\NEW\Log\ServerOutput\$server01.txt"

$file4 = "E:\path\path\path\NEW\Log\ServerOutput\$server02.txt"

$d = Get-Date -Format "ddMMMyyyy"

$t = Get-Date -DisplayHint Time

$serverList = (Get-Content $file1) -replace '#.*' | Where-Object { $_.Trim() -ne '' }

$arr = $serverList -split ' '

$server01 = $arr[0]

$server02 = $arr[1] 

$server01 > $filePath3\$server01.txt

$t >> $filePath3\$server01.txt

$check01 = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server01 {
cd E:\path\path
sqlplus -s user/pass@instance '@LOB_QUEUE_CHECK.sql'
}

$check01 >> $filePath3\$server01.txt

$server02 > $filePath3\$server02.txt

$t >> $filePath3\$server02.txt

$check02 = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server02 {
cd E:\path\path
sqlplus -s user/pass@instance '@LOB_QUEUE_CHECK.sql'
}

$check02 >> $filePath3\$server02.txt

$CheckFile = Test-Path $filePath2\$file2
if ($CheckFile)
    {continue}
else {New-Item -ItemType File -Path $filePath2\$file2}

Get-Content $filePath3\$server01.txt >> $filePath2\$file2

Get-Content $filePath3\$server02.txt >> $filePath2\$file2
```

Problem: When I put this into a PS script, and run from cmd or PS I get the exact results I desire, and no errors (even when I copy it all out and paste it direct to the PS commandline).  However, when I set this script to be run by a Scheduled Task, I get nothing more than the servername ($server01) and time ($t) printed to the target files.  I'll update with a few variations I've attempted thus far (based on suggestions from TechNet and here), but regrettably no success thus far.

And...sorry for the huge post...I was born with the -vv option enabled.

Comment: One of the suggestions my manager made was to just run the sql statement as part of a JobScheduler function in the DB itself, and have it spool out to a file which my script could touch to get what it wants.  I considered this, but 1) I need the timestamp to be consistent with whatever data is retrieved, B- We aren't proper DBA's so much as DB managers/firefighters, iii> I don't want to add anything to a DB system which has stability problems (our design not underlying software) as it is.

Comment: So you get the server 01 and time printed, then the script gets to `Invoke-Command` and crashes out and none of the rest runs? What account is the scheduled task running as? If it's a default system account, it probably won't have permissions to connect over the network. How is the scheduled task configured - is it using `-RunAs` paremeter to PowerShell? What is the 'result' of the scheduled task run in the scheduled tasks UI?

Comment: It does "Get-Content" from the server files to the log.  It is running as a local admin/domain admin account (mine).  I will double check the account aspect.  Scheduled Task - Program: powershell.exe, Arguments: Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass "script", Start In: "path where script resides".  The 'result' is that it will show as "running", but doesn't appear to be closing after completion (probably need to fix my script some more).  I'll try the `-RunAs` suggestion.

Comment: So I checked my config for the scheduled task, and I am using the runas option in the arguments.  I tried having task start the *.ps1 directly (with arguments), and having the task run a bat which initiates the script, with the same results.

Comment: I've been doing some more looking, and I can only assume (haven't confirmed yet) that there is a firewall or cross enclave restriction somewhere that I haven't readily identified.  I'll update if/when I can determine that to be the case.

Comment: We eventually developed an alternative methodology.  Thanks everyone for your input.